# Possibilities of x in a right angle tringle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am stumped on the following question:

> > Which of the following could be the value of x in the diagram a)10 b)20 c)30 d)40 e)50 (Ans b and c)

[image]

Any suggestions relating to solving this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle must be between $90$ and $180$ degrees and is equal to $5x.$ All options for $x$ other than b) and c) imply $5x$ is out of this range, so b) and c) are the only possibilities. Without any more information, the angle could indeed take on the value of either 100 or 150 degrees, so both b) and c) are attainable.